# Check multiple variables arent empty without IF statement jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to build a client side validation on my form and I'm wondering if theres a better way to do it than I imagined?

If a field is empty, then I want the parent container border to turn red, I could d this with a list of if statements...

```
// Complete Signup Validation
$("#signup-com-btn").click(function() {

    var a = $("input.first_name").val();
    var b = $("input.surname").val();
    var c = $("input.email_addr").val();
    var d = $("input.user_age").val();
    var e = $("select.user_type").val();
    var f = $(".profile_image").val();

    if(a==''){
        $(this).parent().css...
        return false;
    }
    if(b==''){
        $(this).parent().css...
        return false;
    }       

...and so on...

});
```

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is an OR? ||

Comment: I was going to use an OR operator but then I wouldnt know which input parent to add the error styling onto?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood I envisioned one big border around them all for some reason, some good answers below now..

Answer (score 1):

apply same class to all

```
var valid = true;
$('.className').each(function(){
  if($(this).val() == ""){
   $(this).parent()....  
     valid = false;
  }  
});
 return valid ;
```

Write this in click  function

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest.  jQuery is very much oriented to manipulating a document that already expresses relationships, so addressing them all with a common class is not only easier, but also a better practice.  

Your class name could be something like .required - and you will see this sort of pattern on validation frameworks as it allows you to declare an input as required simply by adding the class and not changing the validation code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do them all in one loop, if it really is **all** of them:

```
$('#signup-com-btn').click(function() {
    var valid = true; // optimist

    $('input, select, .profile_image').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            valid = false;
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        }
    }

    if(!valid)
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input, select, .profile_image').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).val().length;
}).parent().css('border-color', '#f00');
```

Though I'd prefer to use classes, in order to identify the relevant items *and* to style the parent element, rather than manually modifying CSS rules, to give:

```
$('.inputClassName').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).val().length;
}).parent().addClass('redBorder');
```

Comment: value is not a valid property for select or img elements.

Comment: As for the `select` element, that's true (*edited*); as for the `.profile_image` element? I have no idea what type of element that is (I'm *assuming* it's a file-`input`, but it's purely a guess).

Comment: i don't know either, but i'm guessing it is an img element

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and simulate a foreach loop. Here a Javascript example:

```
function check_empty(){
    var a = document.getElementById('a')
    var b = document.getElementById('b')
    var c = document.getElementById('c')

    var abc = new Array(a, b, c);

    for(i=0; i<abc.length; i++){
        //do your if stuff here...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

since you're using jquery, jquery validation is a nice option that covers most of your form validation needs!

http://plugins.jquery.com/validation/